# Retrieving a guzzle JSON post with simple php

Tags: php, json, post, guzzle

I'm trying to retrieve a result from a `guzzle` json post using simple php.

this is my function in file1.php **EDITED** this file is in a laravel 5.3 project

```
    public function getPhotos($properties)
    {
        $codes = [];
        foreach($properties as $property)
        {
            $codes[$property['codigo']] = $property['cod_filial'];
        }
        $client = new Client();
        $response = $client->request('POST', 'http://local.app/file2.php', ['json' => \GuzzleHttp\json_encode($codes)]);
        var_dump($response); exit;
    }
```

and this is my file in a local url `http://local.app/file2.php` **edited** this file is in a project outside laravel and i have  endpoint configured pointing.

```
<?php
$input = file_get_contents('php://input');;
$input = json_decode($input);
return $input;
```

Guzzle response is empty and i'm not figuring out what i'm doing wrong.

Can someone help me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try `json_encode()` instead of `var_dump()` in your `getPhotos()`

Comment: i'm using var_dump to see te return in terminal, anyway, json_encode returned `string(2) "{}"`  @AaronW.

Answer (score 0):

1) Try in your first file:

```
var_dump($response->getBody()->getContents());
// or
var_dump((string)$response->getBody());
```

2) Read [the documentation about `json` option](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#json) more carefully, this option accepts simple PHP array, you should not call `json_encode` manually.